# Why doesn't std::bitset come with iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, bitset, std-bitset

It appears that [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) does not come with STL iterators.
Therefore, I cannot do the following:

```
std::bitset<8> bs;
for (auto it: bs) {
    std::cout << "this can not be done out of the box\n";
}
```

Instead I must:

```
std::bitset<8> bs;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < bs.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << bs[i] << '\n';
}
```

Without iterators, I also can't use bitsets with any of the STL algorithms.
Why did the committee decide to exclude iterators from bitset?

Comment: Just as a reference, from B.Stroustrup: "For historical reasons, bitset differs in style from other standard-library classes. ... No iterators are provided. " You can find it in the B.Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language" book. "34.2.2 bitset"

Comment: @StahlRat do you have a link to that?

Comment: @NathanOliver https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kCF4BgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA978&ots=hHkkK-K_dP&dq=stroustrup%20for%20historical%20reasons%2C%20bitset%20differs%20in%20style%20from%20other&pg=PA978#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't think there was ever an actual decision to exclude iterators from bitset.

Rather, bitset is one of the classes that predates the proposal to add the original Standard Template Library to the C++ standard. When it was designed, essentially *none* of the standard library included iterators.

Then, Stepanov's library was proposed for addition, and quite a bit of it was accepted. In response to that, additions were made to some existing classes (e.g., `std::string`) to allow them to be used like the new container classes.

This was all happening quite late in the standards process though--in fact, they already bent the rules in a few places to add what they did. Among other things, just about the same time as the containers/iterators/algorithms were added to the library, the committee voted to consider the standard "feature complete", so from that point onward they'd only work on fixing bugs and such, not adding new features.

As such, even if a proposal had been written to add an iterator interface to `bitset`, about the only way the committee could have accepted it would have been to treat this as a bug being fixed rather than a new feature being added. If there'd been a really solid proposal, I suppose they *could* have done that, but I don't think there was such a proposal, and it would have been stretching the point quite a bit, so even a really good proposal might easily have been rejected.

Since then, there was one proposal, [LEWG 1112](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#1112), that would have added an iterator interface to `std::bitset`. This was proposed for C++11, and was proposed specifically to support the range-based `for` loop that was also being added in C++11. It suffered a rather ignominious fate: it was originally accepted, and wording was drafted. Then it looked like the proposal for adding Concepts to the language would be accepted, so this wording was rewritten to use the shiny, wonderful new concepts. Sometime later, concepts were removed from the language, and rather than rewording the proposal so it no longer depended on concepts, they tentatively marked it as "NAD Future", which means they treated it as not being a defect, and deferred any further work until some (indefinite) time in the future (and as far as I can see, haven't revisited it since).

Comment: It's also important to note that they could not be proper iterators until the committee allows proxy iterators to be genuine iterators. Most algorithms are allowed to assume that what is returned from `*it` is a genuine reference to a genuine `iterator::value_type`, instead of possibly being a proxy object.

Comment: @NicolBolas: That, in itself, apparently didn't bother the committee too much at the time (c.f. `std::vector<bool>`).

Comment: It's more likely that they simply weren't very aware of the problem at the time. Particularly with how easy it is to under-specify behavior without explicit concepts. Not that it took very long to discover of course; [the first widely publicized discussion of the problem being in 1999](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill09.htm); shortly after standardization but well after STL had been in semi-wide use.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Oh, I don't think they were really entirely aware of the problem at the time--I just mean that they used a proxy iterator in one place already, so adding a second wouldn't necessarily have been a huge leap in itself.

Comment: Oh. I was thinking more in terms of why they didn't add them in C++11/14.

Comment: @NicolBolas: There, the closest it seems to have come was in [LEWG issue 1112](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#1112), where they initially proposed adding iterators to support range-based for loops, then changed it to use Concept-based wording, then changed to "NAD Future" when concepts were removed.

Comment: @RexYuan: At least as far as I can see, it still doesn't have iterator support.

Comment: It's 2021 now! We have concepts! go go go `std::bitset<N>::iterator`!

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own iterator, or just use [mine](https://gist.github.com/diegum/c719a91065b8b5915ecd484d0584269a)

Usage is as follows:

```
#include <bitset>
#include "bitset_iterator.h"

std::bitset<32> indices{ 0b10101010101010101010101010101010 };

for (const auto& index : indices) {
  std::cout << index << ", ";
}
// Prints "1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, "
```

Comment: That is not how iterators work. They need to return reference to the element in the container.